# probability density function of forecast's percent error

Tags: probability, distributions, measurement-error

Imagine that I am trying to estimate the "number of sales (dollars)" that a client will have when they host a booth at a music festival. The "low forecast" and "high forecast" are based on some very general assumptions (# of employees working, # of products, etc).

For the "low forecast", I'm assuming that we have 12 employees working, each of them selling the same amount of products at a given price (`num employees` * `num of products sold per employee` * `product price`). For the "high forecast", I'm assuming that we have 18 employees working, each of them selling the same amount of products at the same price. All other variables stay the same, only changing the number of employees working will between the two forecasts.

I have calculated the `absolute percent error` for each low and high forecast, and I've also taken the log of these. If I were to map the Probability Distribution of the percent errors (one for 'low', one for 'high') - would I be correct in saying:

- "the probability that *X* takes on a value between [0, 15] would be the area on under the curve" ?
- "if that area under the curve is 50%, then we can say that there's a 50% probability that the percent error is less than or equal to 15%"?

| entry | ee_salary | low_forecast | high_forecast | low_perc_err | high_perc_err | log_low_perc_error | log_high_perc_error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9414.78 | 5595.04 | 11190.08 | 40.57 | 18.86 | 3.70 | 2.94 |
| 2 | 11431.13 | 5009.60 | 10019.20 | 56.18 | 12.35 | 4.03 | 2.51 |
| 3 | 717.00 | 1008.00 | 2016.00 | 40.59 | 181.17 | 3.70 | 5.20 |
| 4 | 2039.01 | 2160.00 | 4320.00 | 5.93 | 111.87 | 1.78 | 4.72 |
| 5 | 11020.84 | 5595.04 | 11190.08 | 49.23 | 1.54 | 3.90 | 0.43 |
| 6 | 5604.17 | 2327.76 | 4655.52 | 58.46 | 16.93 | 4.07 | 2.83 |
| 7 | 3382.41 | 3654.00 | 7308.00 | 8.03 | 116.06 | 2.08 | 4.75 |
| 8 | 9391.64 | 6240.40 | 12480.80 | 33.55 | 32.89 | 3.51 | 3.49 |
| 9 | 16059.72 | 8280.40 | 16560.80 | 48.44 | 3.12 | 3.88 | 1.14 |
| 10 | 14325.89 | 8088.00 | 16176.00 | 43.54 | 12.91 | 3.77 | 2.56 |
| 11 | 1200.00 | 176000.00 | 352000.00 | 14566.67 | 29233.33 | 9.59 | 10.28 |
| 12 | 15802.69 | 8088.00 | 16176.00 | 48.82 | 2.36 | 3.89 | 0.86 |
| 13 | 17598.17 | 9056.80 | 18113.60 | 48.54 | 2.93 | 3.88 | 1.07 |
| 14 | 15685.40 | 9056.80 | 18113.60 | 42.26 | 15.48 | 3.74 | 2.74 |
| 15 | 18308.17 | 9364.40 | 18728.80 | 48.85 | 2.30 | 3.89 | 0.83 |

Comment: You need to tell us how exactly did you obtain the forecasts? Otherwise it is hard to answer. What do "low" and "high" actually mean in here?

Comment: @Tim I have updated the question - do you mind giving it a look and letting me know if I need to provide more information? Essentially - this is a rough forecast and I am just trying to quantify which forecast is better, and by "how much".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you assume the price to be fixed and are ok with the assumption that each employee sells the same number of products. You want to learn how does the variability of the number of available employees can influence the result. This cannot be done by assuming only the low and the high number of employees, at least without making any additional assumptions that would make the result rather arbitrary.

What you could do is to look at some historical data to learn what is the distribution of the available employees. You would either look at the [empirical distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) or assume some parametric distribution, let’s say [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with $\lambda$ equal to the average number of employees. In such a case, for every number of employees in `num employees` * `num of products sold per employee` * `product price`, you could assign the probability from the distribution and use it to construct the distribution of the outcomes. This is possible because you are using a very simple [function of a random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable) here.

For example, using those made-up numbers

```r
> num_products_sold <- 100
> price <- 50
> num_employees <- seq(5, 25, 1)
> lambda <- (12 + 18) / 2  # let's assume this as an average number of employees
```

for different numbers of employees, we can expect the following outcomes

```r
> num_employees * num_products_sold * price
 [1]  25000  30000  35000  40000  45000  50000  55000  60000  65000  70000
[11]  75000  80000  85000  90000  95000 100000 105000 110000 115000 120000
[21] 125000
```

each of them, happening with the following probabilities:

```r
> dpois(num_employees, lambda)
 [1] 0.001935788 0.004839470 0.010370294 0.019444300 0.032407167 0.048610751
 [7] 0.066287387 0.082859234 0.095606809 0.102435867 0.102435867 0.096033625
[13] 0.084735551 0.070612960 0.055747073 0.041810305 0.029864504 0.020362162
[19] 0.013279671 0.008299794 0.004979876
```

and an expected value of

```r
> sum(num_employees * num_products_sold * price * dpois(num_employees, lambda))
[1] 74146.79
```

Knowing the distribution, you can easily calculate the probabilities of the outcomes.